# Get the name of "named data range" from a cell in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a range of data that I want to use `vlookup` on. I named the range as "june_salaries". The goal is to generate payslips for each employee based on the data range (june_salaries).

My query is that is there a way to instead of writing something like

```
=VLOOKUP($B$6,june_salaries,4,0)
```

I can simply refer to a single cell for the "named range"? For example, let's say I put the text "june_salaries" in cell A1, and when I use `vlookup`, for the range of data I will simply refer to that cell.

The reason why I want to do that this way is the salary sheet changes each month and so is the name of the range. But if I can refer the data range in a single cell, I can simply change the name of the month from June to July or anything.

Hope the query is clear. Please let me know if further information would be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `june_salaries` in F1. Wrap your named range name in [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377):

```
=VLOOKUP($B$6,indirect(F1),4,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned, you can use `INDIRECT` to reference a cell value/string and reflect it into a formula

```
=VLOOKUP(B6, INDIRECT(F1), 4, 0)
```

array formula (if needed) of that would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B6:B, INDIRECT(F1), 4, 0)))
```

HOWEVER, you could automate it (if you plan to edit F1 cell once per month for each month)

```
=VLOOKUP(B6, 
 INDIRECT(LOWER(TEXT(DATE(2000, MONTH(TODAY())-1, 1), "mmmm"))&"_salaries"), 4, 0)
```

eg. this month it will return you `june_salaries`, next month it will return you `july_salaries`, etc.